# MySQL: Remove character in whole Database

Tags: mysql, database, field

I have a field called `higlights` in my database. In that fields I store the higlights of the products. Now the higlights field looks like this:

```
"some higlight"; "another highlight"; "blabla"; "etc"
```

I want convert all those records in my database to:

```
some higlight; another highlight; blabla; etc
```

What is the most productive way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are just trying to remove the double quotes, then you would do:

```
update tableName
    set highlights = replace(highlights, '"', '')
    where highlights like '%"%';
```

Comment: What is the purpose of aliasing the table name here and I guess a `where` clause can be omitted too, right?

Comment: @asprin . . . The `where` clause can be omitted.  Some databases will count records as changed, even when there are no changes.  I don't think MySQL does this, but I use `where` clauses in these situations out of habit for performance.

Comment: Oh..ok, wasn't aware of that weird behavior